# Is there a way to recolor different data sets on the same histogram in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

This is currently what my line of code looks like:

**`plt.hist((method_a,method_b,method_c), bins=np.linspace(lb,ub,20), histtype='stepfilled', alpha = 0.5)`**

and I would like for method_a, method_b, and method_c to have different colored bars on the same histogram. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib-pyplot-hist), matplotlib's plt.hist() takes a `color` keyword argument where you can specify an array of colours per data series, eg:

```
plt.hist((method_a,method_b,method_c), bins=np.linspace(lb,ub,20), color=['blur', 'red', 'green'], histtype='stepfilled', alpha = 0.5)
```

[More information on colours can be found here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html)